# will my site be slow in amazon cloud if server is not in my country

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I want to use and try cloud computing. The two options are GAE and Amazon, but I hate google data store so I don't want to use that.

But amazon doesn't have cloud in Australia, so if I buy that service in the US will my site be slow if people access it from my country?

Comment: Well, what kind of pings do you normally get to US-based sites? Physical location rarely has much to do with network latency. You neighbor's machine could be "farther" away than a machine in the US, if your ISP and the neighbor's don't do direct peering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS has an endpoint in Southeast Asia for the majority of their services. If you're in Australia, that's probably the one you want to hit.

You said "Amazon", so I assume you're talking about EC2 and S3. If you're talking about Elastic Beanstalk, it's *currently* US-only, but it's not rocket surgery to figure out that they'll roll it out to other regions at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Slower than if it were in your country.

Light can only travel so fast. It takes a dozen or two milliseconds to travel from Australia to Europe or to United States, and the same to get back. No communication (fiber optics, copper cable) is faster than light, so it's always going to be slower talking to servers on the other side of the planet than those that are close by.

Is it too slow? Not compared to hosting with anyone else outside your country. Amazon's network is certainly fast.

Comment: i rememebr when i buy hosting in US from various hosting companies (Shared hosting) then usually my upload speed via ftp comes to max 8kb/s and download of max 100-200. but in australia its about max upload speed and max download. so i really dont't want something loke that

Comment: It's not like you have to guess. Amazon has a free tier. Start up an instance and download a file.